# PRESENT SIMPLE OR FUTURE SIMPLE

Tags: conditionals

Could someone help me with this sentence: 
- If you are a well-organised person, you (manage - will manage) your time. 
Thank you all.

Comment: Either is possible. Why do you think only one can be right?

Comment: The question's already been asked here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214414/need-answer-to-an-if-question (it'd be nice if someone answered it, or this one). By the way, please see this, https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour, and this, https://ell.stackexchange.com/help. It would be nice if you told us why you're having trouble with this question (which pertinent "rules" you know and, in this case, what you'd say the "correct" answer is, etc.). You can edit your post (there's a label with the word *edit* underneath it) in order to provide this additional info.